# Change background color of communication site in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, communication-site, spcolor

How do i change the background color of the communication site that i inserted table in a text web part to be no color(No gray or any other color).

I just tried using Text and table formatting in the web part, but doesn't change it. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the table style to Plain. Select the table and change it to the first style (Plain).

[image]

If your table is pasted from the Word/Excel, we cannot change its style using Text and table formatting toolbar.

You need to format it in the Word/Excel, then copy the table from the Word/Excel and paste it to the Text web part on the modern page.

Comment: I tried, but doesn't definitely work. Sorry JoannaW-MSFT

Comment: Have you tried to format the table in Word/Excel?

Comment: I tried both ways:                                                                                1- Doing from outside SharePoint(word) and paste to web part.      
2- Doing using text web part by inserting table use plain style. All are same result.

Comment: Please create a new page and test. Also, test in another site.